# Можно ли как-то свойстваv присвоить названия на русском языке и нижних подчеркиваний?

Tags: c#, sql, сервер, dapper

Вопрос весь глупый и странный, вот собственно в чем вся суть:
можно ли как-то свойствам присвоить названия на русском языке и без нижних подчеркиваний? Пытаюсь подключить базу данных с помощью Dapper'a.

```
        public string Mark { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Year_of_issue { get; set; }
        public string Plate_number { get; set; }
        public string Mileage_or_running_time { get; set; }
        public string Maintenance { get; set; }
        public string Repairs { get; set; }
        public string Date_of_completion { get; set; }
```

Comment: Вы хотите получать имена в вашей программе на русском, или по русским названиям вытаскивать данные из столбцов, уточните пожалуйста!

Comment: Получать имена из свойств на русском языке. Пример: Year_of_issue - Год выпуска.

Comment: Если же вариантов не будет, тогда можно будет и имена брать из столбцов бд, только не совсем понятно, как это сделать в Dapper'e.

Comment: Также вы можете сделать свой маппер реализуя SqlMapper.ITypeMap и в нем определить правила трансляции имен. Например добавить поддержку аттрибута [Column("колонка")] или словарик с переводами. Dapper.FluentMap так и делает. Хотя сложно понять что вы задумали.

Comment: Мне именно это и нужно, но я не сильно разбираюсь в программировании, Ваши советы слишком сложны для меня.

Answer (score 1):

Просто избавиться от нижних подчеркиваний, может помочь такая настройка:

```
Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
```

[Dapper.FluentMap](https://github.com/henkmollema/Dapper-FluentMap) позволит задать свой маппинг полей класса на поля таблицы.

```
public class UsersMap : EntityMap<users>
{
    public UsersMap()
    {
        Map(t => t.UserId).ToColumn("user_id");
        Map(t => t.CompanyId).ToColumn("company_id");
        Map(t => t.UserTypeId).ToColumn("user_type_id");
        Map(t => t.UserAccessId).ToColumn("user_access_id");
        Map(t => t.DateAdded).ToColumn("date_added");
        Map(t => t.DateModified).ToColumn("date_modified");
        Map(t => t.AddedBy).ToColumn("added_by");
        Map(t => t.ModifiedBy).ToColumn("modified_by");
    }
}
```

Но вообще, чего-либо отличного от латиницы в именованиисущностей и их составляющих лучше избегать. На интерфейсе всегда можно сделать "красоту" с локализацией независимо.

Comment: А как это все применить к моей задаче?

Comment: @IvanLabozhevich, название полей вашего класса больше не будут обязаны совпадать с названиями полей таблицы.

Comment: @IvanLabozhevich, как я понял, ваша проблема в том, что именование полей в БД сильно отличается от стиля кода, принятого в C#. По-умолчанию, чтобы Dapper понял какое поле класса к какому полю таблицы относится, он просто ищет совпадение буква-в-букву. А эта библиотека (Dapper.FluentMap) позволяет для каждого класса задать правило такого сопоставления: допустим, свойство `CompanyId` сможет принимать данные из поля `company_id` таблицы.

Comment: Вы все правильно понимаете.